# Parse Cloud Code Query in a loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, underscore.js, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to make a Parse cloud code function that retrieves a "Score" but it`s level and owner, if it exists, update and else create it.
I can not make it work inside a loop to repeat this over a list of score to update or insert.

Below is a code I adapted from https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-chaining that reproduces my issue.

My resultMessage outputs:

> {"result":" loop  loop "}

Instead of

> {"result":" loop set 100  find  set 200  success find  loopset 100 
>   find  set 200  success "}

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("example2", function(request, response) {
 var resultMessage = ""
 var query = new Parse.Query("ScoreTest");
 var test = ["1", "2"]; // Dumb list to loop over.
 var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
 promise = promise.then(function() { 
  _.each(test, function(elt) {
   resultMessage = resultMessage + " loop ";
   query.find().then(function(students) {
    resultMessage = resultMessage + " set 100 ";
     students[0].set("score", 100);
     return students[0].save();
    
   }).then(function(valedictorian) {
    resultMessage = resultMessage + " find ";
     return query.find();
    
   }).then(function(students) {
    resultMessage = resultMessage + " set 200 ";
     students[0].set("salutatorian", 200);
     return students[0].save();
    
   }).then(function(salutatorian) {
     resultMessage = resultMessage + " success ";
     return Parse.Promise.as();
     
   });
  });
 }).then(function() {
  response.success(resultMessage);
 })
 
});
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to execute those in parallel, i.e. `loop loop set100 set100 find find set200 set200 success success`?

Comment: Please edit the question and include a clear description of the functional goal.  The text is incomplete (needs a description of the classes, their columns, column types), needs a clearer description of what are the criteria on the find and the desired outcome.  Sometimes, readers here can look to the code to clarify the question's intent, but the posted code is nearly incomprehensible.  (I realize that's why you're here asking the question, so lets get it clear in English to start with).

Comment: @ Bergi: I don't think I can because in the end I want to retrieve a score and update it with the input parameters. If the calls are asynchronous, I'll update all objects with the data of the last element of my input table. But you may be right, I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: @danh: sorry if you did not understand. As stated in the description, the pasted code is only reproducing my issue and the expected behavior is logging in the output message in the correct order to check that the calls are synchronous indeed. The object structure does not matter at all in this case, I am only worried about having each call blocking the next one until it has finished.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was led astray by the posted code.  Lets say the problem is just this: retrieve an object by some criteria.  If it exists, modify and save it.  If it does not exist, create it. Do all that inside a loop.

Lets do it with small, promise-returning functions for each logical bit:

```
// return a promise for a Score matching level and owner.  return
// undefined if one doesn't exist
function scoreWithOwnerLevel(owner, level) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Score");
    query.equalTo("owner", owner);
    query.equalTo("level", level);
    return query.first();
}

// return a promise for either an existing score or a new one matching
// level and owner criteria.  set its otherValue
function findOrCreateScore(owner, level, otherValue) {
    return scoreWithOwnerLevel(owner, level).then(function(score) {
        if (!score) {
            var Score = Parse.Object.extend("Score");
            score = new Score();
            score.set("owner", owner);
            score.set("level", level);
        }
        score.set("otherValue", param.otherValue);
        return score;
    });
}

// take a list of owners, levels and one other value. find
// or create scores for these based on score and level.
// assign each the other values and save.  assume that params 
// of the form [{ owner:'sam', level:2, otherValue:'foo'}, ... etc.]
function findOrCreateScoresWith(params) {
    var scores = _.map(params, function(param) {
        return findOrCreateScore(param.owner, param.level, param.otherValue);
    });
    return Parse.Object.saveAll(scores);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. First I have to comment the line
 
`score.set("otherValue", param.otherValue);`

to remove an error:

**TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'**

Comment: My bad. I was uncomfortable about something on that first draft, just couldn't put my finger on it.  Clearly we must update the object after it is found or created.  So moved that to the fulfillment of the find or create promise.  The code I suggested originally was trying to manipulate the promise, not the object.  Sorry, and please see edit.